# Index Error while transposing a 5x5 array

Tags: ruby, arrays, transpose

Given the following "bingo board" array:

```
board =        [[47, 44, "X", 8, 88],
                [22, 69, "X", 65, 73],
                [83, 85, "X", 89, 57],
                [25, 31, "X", 68, 51],
                [75, 70, "X", 80, 83]]
```

and running the following method to see if I have a bingo:

```
def bingo(board)
  if board.each_index {|e| board[e].uniq!} .any? {|row| row == ["X"]} == true
    p "BINGO!"
  elsif
    board = board.transpose
    board.each_index {|e| board[e].uniq!} .any? {|row| row == ["X"]} == true
    p "BINGO!"
  elsif (board[0][0] && board[1][1] && board[2][2] && board[3][3] && board[4][4]) == "X"
    p "BINGO!"
  elsif board[0][4] && board[1][3] && board[2][2] && board[3][1] && board[4][0] == "X"
    p "BINGO!"
  else
    p "no bingo"
  end
end
```

I'm running into the following error:

```
`transpose': element size differs (5 should be 4) (IndexError)
```

What gives? Why does it think 5 be 4?

Comment: Not getting the same mistake but check @Myst answear.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question but there is no need to use `== true` in your conditions. In Ruby everything is treated true except `false` and `nil`

Comment: Thanks @shivam. Still new to this. myst is correct that was the problem. But now boards with no bingos are evaluating as a bingo so something else is wrong haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your second line, running `board[e].uniq!` changes each of the arrays nested within the original `board` array destructively... hence, there are no longer five objects in each line.